# How do I delete a subsite without navigating to the subsite?

Tags: 2013

I'm getting an error on subsite that I want to delete, and that error prevents me from getting to the site. I need to delete the site without having to navigate to it. Any ideas?

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: could you please add the steps, which you follow and error you are getting? it will help us to understand the issue and respond accordingly.

Comment: you may be able to get to it by using appending `_layouts/settings.aspx` to the url like so: `http://sitecollection/subsite/_layouts/settings.aspx`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Site Settings -> Site Administration -> Content and Structure -> find your sub site and delete it. This will help you with out navigate to your sub site.

Answer (score 1):

In such case you can use Powershell script to delete the subsite without navigating it.

Here is the powershell script that will delete the subsite for you.

```
$SiteURL = "http://intranet.crescent.com/sites/operations/us"
#Get the site
$web = Get-SPWeb $SiteURL
#Delete the subsite
$web.Delete()
```

Read more: [How to Delete Subsite In SharePoint 2013 using PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/11/delete-subsite-in-sharepoint-2013-using-powershell.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `PnPPowerShell`

> Remove-PnPWeb -Url   -Force

hope this could help you to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

I found an earlier version of the sub-site in my internet history (before I had made the changes that caused the error to be caught) and just deleted it from the the normal way. I'm not sure if any of the above answers work because I had already managed to delete the page before checking back.